# How to change the colors in the Eclipse spell suggestion?

Tags: eclipse, ide, spell-checking

As you can see there is nothing to see in the spell suggestion window:

[image]

How can I change at the colors so it becomes readable?

I am using this Eclipse version on SLES 12.3:

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>
> Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
>
> Build id: 20170314-1500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [improved in Oxygen](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#colors-interactive-popups). Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F).

Comment: How to install for Oxygen the rdt-server? The host/server is on linux and Eclipse Oxygen is running on Windows? Any hint? THX!

Comment: @AlBundy I don't know (I am not a C/C++ developer), but maybe you don't have to install anything in Oxygen: _Window > Preferences: Remote Development_.